# How to programmatically add exception for unidentifed .app

Tags: macos, cocoa, command-line, macos-carbon

When I create a `.app` on the desktop of mac os x 10.9, and when user clicks it, they get "unidentified developer" error.

However if they right click, then click open, then from dialog box click open, it adds an exception so in future launches it doesnt throw the "unidentified developer" error and launches.

I was wondering what is the programmatic way or command line or carbon or cocoa api to programmatically add this exception. i know code signing is an option but that requires purhcase of 100$ license, i just want to make a shortcut on the desktop for users of my addon.

image of adding exception with right click > open > open:

[image: image of adding exception with right click > open > open]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's possible to remove the `Quarantine Flag` `xattr` from your application using:

```
xattr -d com.apple.quarantine My.app
```

Comment: It works! Thanks man! However it only works from terminal. It even works if I launch `/usr/bin/xattr` with argumens `-d com.apple.quarantine My.app`, this is expected right? thanks man!! i struggled with this for 2 days!! haha

Comment: Is it possible to just write some info in `Info.plist` file so I don't have to do this `xattr`?

Comment: For instance, if i create the .app from script editor and save it then open it to show contents, then look at the `Info.plist` its contents is this: https://gist.github.com/Noitidart/7f4aa4da416bf84eba73#comment-1302468  i tried using this plist.info but i cant get it to bypass the unidentified error. just cruious because i was hoping to do this without having to run any command line stuff

Comment: @Noitidart, You could make a script that would automatically run the terminal command. Is that sort of what you mean? The command isn't necessarily bound to Terminal — for instance you could create an `Applescript`, or `.command` to remove the `xattr`. It's also possible to turn off quarantine completely, but I'd recommend against doing that.

Comment: Oh i think so `xattr` is the only way to get around this huh? I definitely dont want to turn off the users quarantine. Just allow the single one they are actually giving permission to my addon to make. I was just thinking if i put some special words in `info.plist` we could avoid `xattr` but i think thats the only way huh? super thanks i struggled for 3 days to figure this one out

Comment: There are a couple other things you could try: 1. (if your app is sandboxed), you should set `com.apple.security.files.user-selected.executable` as an entitlement for your script application. See the `NOTE` in the section titled "[Enabling User-Selected File Access](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Miscellaneous/Reference/EntitlementKeyReference/Chapters/EnablingAppSandbox.html)". 2. Add a key to your plist `<key>LSFileQuarantineEnabled</key></false>`

Comment: Thanks man I'll research that and report back what I learn! :)

Comment: btw - `</false>` should be `<false/>` in the plist :)